# SQL - Insert in a single Table different Count from another Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, insert, where-clause

From this table,

```
FLAG    CONO
MMS001  100
MMS001  100
MMS001  300
MMS001  700
MMS001  700
MMS001  700
```

I would like to Count the number of '100', '300', '700, and '800' in the column "CONO", and insert into a single table, like this one :

```
NB_ROWS      NB_100      NB_300      NB_700      NB800
6            2           1           3           0
```

I'm struggling with using multiple `WHERE`.
I use ACCESS for this.

Thank you guys for your help !

Comment: OK. I use ACCESS.

Comment: Do you really want to insert the results into a new or existing table, or do you just want the results?

Comment: Yes, I would like to insert into a new Table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation in MS Access as:

```
select count(*) as NB_ROWS, 
       sum(iif(CONO = 100, 1, 0)) as NB_100,
       sum(iif(CONO = 300, 1, 0)) as NB_300,
       sum(iif(CONO = 700, 1, 0)) as NB_700,
       sum(iif(CONO = 800, 1, 0)) as NB_800
from t;
```